# Sounds for killing people (chainsaw and hammer)

Tags: film-sound-design

Hy everyone.

Im work on a film wich 2 characters killing people in 2 short scene.
One with a hammer (he always beat first to the head), the other with a chainsaw (he just cut the bodys).:)

The bloody parts happens always offscreen(we just see the splashing blood), so im very free to build the sound dramaturgy.

This is my first real sound design, and im relay want to record everything for this 2 scene, so i would very happy with the proposals.:)
What next? buy some coconut, fruit, vegtables and meat?:)

Comment: I love the title to this post!

Answer (score 3):

Social Sound Design has been a great resource to me over the years and I've gained a lot of knowledge from all of the people contributing. And in an effort to keep that momentum going I choose to post an answer to this question - with reservations.

I do not like the title of this question. Nor do I like the grotesque escalation of violence in every form of media, especially lately in light of the latest round of mass killings in America (most notably the murder of a classroom full of kindergarten age children), it makes me sick to my stomach to think that watching people die on screen is considered "entertainment". To be called upon by directors and producers to create the sounds of torture porn, murder and death for people to sit and watch strikes me as - absolutely wrong. But hey, who am I to argue? The public eats this crap up like biscuits and gravy.

All that being said, I will offer up this piece of creative sound design advice, had I been put in your position of needing to create it: A chainsaw cutting through most any object will have a strain put on its motor, causing it to "bog down" temporarily. If you construct the chainsaw engine with this in mind you will probably lead the audience to think that the saw is really working hard to cut its way through. And people will most likely love that and tell all their friends how gross it was, and we will all continue to become desensitized to the violence around us.

Comment: I totally agree with u Jay. Of course, all we have a social responsibility who are working in this industry, (if u are involved). The misundarstanding could come from different media culture, and politics maybe...Here in Europe is little bit different. This title means just pictures and challenging for me, for others the violence in there environment.

Answer (score 2):

A steak and a hammer should give you what you want and as long as you use clean implements you'll have something for your tea afterwards  ;-)

The inside of a watermellon also works well for some nice squishy sounds that you can layer up.

Not sure you'd hear much cutting sound over a chainsaw.

Have fun.

PS.  Watch your mic placements as you don't want your expensive kit getting covered in goo!!!!

Comment: :)) haha:) i don't think i use it in the kitchen afterwards:)
yeah, watermelon is a good idea!! and its maybe good for the skull too!
chainsaw..yes, maybe we cant hear nothing, but what happens if i have to overact it for director instructions?

Comment: You need to put a case forward for how YOU think it should sound.  At the end of the day it should be a collaboration.  Having said that, if forced you'll have to go with what the director wants. Maybe have a chainsaw burst followed by the resulting squelch.  Kind of cause and effect.

Comment: I'm trying to implement my own ideas of course. 
maybe when the chainsaw cut the bodys, it have some "flesh tone" or something.....im trying and after i share the resoult:) 

Comment: Cool.  Let us know how it goes.

Comment: of course!! is post it to here:)

Answer (score 2):

Tomatoes work great, they have just the right acidity for queezy squelchy sounds, grapefruit as well.  Using a towel to create wrapped squishes adds a nice weight to them too.  I'll admit that despite the scale of gore activity in a scene, I keep coming back to that tomato workup.

As the saying goes, we call horror films "produce films" ;)

Comment: i have to try it all out! tomatos have good moisture content.

its not a typical horror, but we work a lot after the shooting in the studios:))

Answer (score 0):

i almost forgot

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhJtj24e22A

Answer (score 0):

https://getsoundeffects.com/#/products-page/sound-effects/halloween-horror/

Track 4 is my Chainsaw Massacre track I made, maybe this will help you with some ideas.

-Benjie